# How to create function that returns 'change in highest denominations'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a programme that will return the correct change, in the highest denominations possible

i.e $73 will return 1 x $50, 1 x $20, 1 x $2 and 1 $1

(I am using whole values of $100, $50, $20, $10, $5, $2, $1)

I have a long code that works...it is

```
hundred = x // 100
hundred_remainder = x % 100

fifty = hundred_remainder // 50
fifty_remainder = hundred_remainder % 50

twenty = fifty_remainder // 20
```

etc....then

```
if hundred > 0:
    print (str(hundred) + " x $100")
if fifty> 0:
    print (str(fifty) + " x $50")
```

etc....which works fine, but I know there must be a way of writing a function that has a loop to work it out with less typing. Something like X = $345, then it gets 3 x $100, subtracts that from the total and updates X with the remainder, then repeats the process going through each denomination, until complete. I'm just a bit unsure how to figure it out, any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a cool model for this problem is defining the values that you consider "legal" up-front, and then iterating over those from the top to the bottom to reach your counts.  Consider the following loop:

```
    #where x is the value from which you're making change 
    legal = [100,50,20,10,5,2,1,.50,.25,.10,.05,.01]
    for dolAmount in legal:
        count = x//dolAmount
        if count > 0:
            print int(count),\
                  dolAmount,\
                  " coin(s)" if dolAmount<1 else " dollar bill(s)"
        x-=count*dolAmount

    #  prints lines like this for x=103.58:
    #  
    #  1 100 dollar bill(s)
    #  3 1 dollars bill(s) 
    #  1 0.5 coin(s)
    #  1 0.05 coim(s)
    #  3 0.01 coin(s)
    #  ehhh actually it will probably say 2 0.01 coin(s) because floating points....
```

The formatting needs work (what the heck is a 0.5 coin?), but this is a neat way of saving yourself a lot of code-writing, and the pattern is applicable to other programming endeavors.  In general, when you find yourself creating a lot of variables/constants by hand, it's probably time to start thinking about a list (or similar collection)!

Check out http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_ur6ybhs9HAmknOL.py for a learning-example of what this would look like in practice (used within a function!)  Happy coding!

Comment: This is broken because floating point representation of 0.01 is inaccurate. For example, your version fails for "11.76".

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in C a few weeks ago; I do not know Python well, so Im just going to write the logic of the function. Im sure you will be able to translate it flawlessly to Python ;)

We know that the highest bill is that of $100;

So, say we have an ammount of $335.

What we should do first is create an int variable for each Bill denomination.

```
int b100 = 0;
int b50 = 0;
int b20 = 0;
int b10 = 0;
int b5 = 0;
int b2 = 0;
int b1 = 0;
```

Then, we should make a while loop:

```
while(ammount >= 100){
   ammount = ammount - 100;
   b100++;
}
```

here what we did is obtain the total ammount of $100 bills that we'll need. 
After this while loop ammount must be equals to 35, and b100 should have a value of 3;

then we repeat the code with the next bill:

```
while(ammount >= 50){
   ammount = ammount - 50;
   b50++;
}
```

In this case, as ammount has a value of 35, and it's lower that 50, it won't enter the while loop; instead it will pass to the next one:

```
while(ammount >= 20){
   ammount = ammount - 20;
   b20++;
}
```

Etc....

After all those whiles we should have ammount with a value of '0';

And the bills variables with the quantity of bills required.

In the example of $335 the variables value should be like this:

> $100 bills --> 3 $20 bills --> 1 $10 bills --> 1 $5 bills --> 1

Hope it helped, any doubts feel free to ask ;)